# Text Time format into Excel, i need help creating a formula that would do it for me

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I convert `213h25` into an excel time format. I have a text file with hours then an `h` separating the minutes. Do I need a formula instead of doing one by one.

Comment: Do you require the time to be displayed as hours and minutes, rather than days, hours and minutes?

Comment: yes i would like hours and minutes

Answer (score 1):

At first need to clarify that excel doesn't sort time format in your example, everything above one day it does as day, so `213h25` will be converted to 8 days 21 hours and 25 minutes (08/01/1900 21:25 as Excel starts date from 1900), converting it to number, you won't see total number of hours again.

The formula you can use: `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h",":"))`

This will result in a number, set cell's number formatting to the desired one (e.g. "d hh:mm")

Comment: i would like for 213h25 to show as 213:25

Comment: the number format `[h]:mm:ss` is what you want.

Comment: yes, that format is what i want